# Pass "this" (button) as a parameter in TKINTER

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I want to pass **this** as the name of the variable, which is a button in this case, instead of writing each var I want to pass.

where it says:
command = lambda: pop**("AP", AP)**
I would like to have something like:
command = lambda: pop**(str(this), this)**

so I don't have to write every function (**D.R.Y.**)

```py
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("640x640")

arr = ["AC", "AP", "AD", "AT"]
def pop(a,b):
    arr.remove(a)
    b['state'] = tkinter.DISABLED

AP = tkinter.Button(ventana, text= "Button test", padx = 5.33, pady = 25.333, command = lambda: pop("AP", AP), state = tkinter.NORMAL)
```

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: You can't access a variable (`AP`) if you haven't defined it, not even in the same line. Try `AP['command'] = lambda: pop("AP", AP)` in the next line.

Comment: @Saad Actually no, it does work defining it in the same line.

Comment: well suppose I want to add another variable called AC which does the same thing, but instead of removing AP, I would have it remove AC. I should change it to pop("AC", AC). Then suppose I have 50 vars like that: it would be annoying.
Is there any way to pass directly the VAR (AP, AC, AD, AT) depending on which button I click?